# Problem creating gui from xml -> Strange CPButton behaviour

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, objective-j

Hallo,

I'm new to objective-j and cappuccino and just have tried to create a
small application, that creates the gui dynamically from a xml file.

Unfortunately it works only partially. It seems that the button
regions are disorder. This means, that the buttons also  response  if
I click besides the button....

Please help me. I dont get it..

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(CPNotification)aNotification
{

    mControlList = [CPArray alloc];

   theWindow = [[CPWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:CGRectMakeZero()
    styleMask:CPBorderlessBridgeWindowMask],
    contentView = [theWindow contentView];
    [contentView setFrame:[[contentView superview] bounds]];
    [contentView setAutoresizingMask:CPViewWidthSizable |
CPViewHeightSizable];


    // Loadxmlfile
    var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    xhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xhttp.send("");
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

    //Get controls nodeand iterate through all controls
    var node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("controls")[0];
    for (var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(node.childNodes[i].nodeName=="button"){
            var item = node.childNodes[i];

            var name = item.attributes["name"].nodeValue;
            var text = item.getElementsByTagName("text")
[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var x=      item.getElementsByTagName("rect")
[0].attributes["x"].nodeValue;
            var y=      item.getElementsByTagName("rect")
[0].attributes["y"].nodeValue;
            var width=  item.getElementsByTagName("rect")
[0].attributes["width"].nodeValue;
            var height= item.getElementsByTagName("rect")
[0].attributes["height"].nodeValue;

            var b = [[Button alloc] InitWithParent:contentView Text:text X:x
Y:y Width:width Height:height];
            [mControlList addObject:b];
        }
    }

    [theWindow orderFront:self];

}
```

---

```
@implementation Button : CPObject
{
    CPButton _button;
}

- (Button)InitWithParent:(CPView)contentView Text:(CPString)text X:
(int)x Y:(int)y Width:(int)width Height:(int)height
{
    _button = [[CPButton alloc] initWithFrame:
CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    [_button setTitle:text];
    [_button setTarget:self];
    [_button setAction:@selector(cmdNext_onClick:)];
    [contentView addSubview:_button];
    return self;
}

- (void)cmdNext_onClick:(id)sender
{
}
@end
```

Comment: Wouldn't your XML reader produce strings rather than integers? I would test the button code without the XML part.

Comment: Thx, I just fixed it.... You're right, string values must be casted to Number before passing them to CGRectMake. The confusing thing was, that the button was drawn correctly anyway, but only the mouse events didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Cappuccino gives you most of this functionality for free.

You can load files by using a [CPURLConnection](http://cappuccino.org/learn/documentation/class_c_p_u_r_l_connection.html).

Also [Atlas](http://280atlas.com/) (or [Interface Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) and nib2cib) will automatically create cib files for you, Cappuccino itself already knows how to build up it's UI from a cib files.

If you really want to implement your own system to do this, could you please provide the actual XML you are trying to load? Also try loading the button without using the XML. For example:

```
var myButton = [CPButton buttonWithTitle:@"My Cool Button"];
[contentView addSubview:myButton];
```

`+ buttonWithTitle:` will automatically call `- sizeToFit` on the initialized button, so you can just add it to your contentView and it should be visible with the appropriate size.